# Capital gains tax payable in Italy

Tags: taxes, italian-citizens, italy-aire

Is there a reduced rate for the capital gains tax applied to Italian citizens (registered with AIRE) permanently residing overseas?

Comment: Would this be for an Italian based gain, or one overseas?

Comment: No reduced rate. What you have are bilateral agreements between some countries, which ensure you don't pay taxes twice.